# Create RxJs observable based on method availability

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I would like to wait for a method availability before to be executed using RxJs observable and TypeScript inside an Angular 4 application.

So far I came up with using `interval` combine with `skipWhile` but I was wondering **is there a better way to just "watch" the method for it to be available instead of watching every 100ms**?

```js
 Observable
    .interval(100)
    .skipWhile(() => myObject.myFunction == null)
    .first()
    .subscribe(() => myObject.myFunction());
```

I'm pretty new to Observable so any insight is welcome!

```js
// create element without sayHello function
const myElement = {};

// add method sayHello after 1000ms that show an alert
setTimeout(() => myElement.sayHello = () => alert('Hello'), 1000);

// watch every 100ms if sayHello function exist before to execute it
Rx.Observable
  .interval(100)
  .skipWhile((interval) => {
    const isUndefined = myElement.sayHello == null;
    write(interval, isUndefined);
    return isUndefined;
  })
  .first()
  .subscribe(() => myElement.sayHello());

// function to write result to DOM
const write = (interval, isUndefined) => {
  const node = document.createElement("DIV");
  const textnode = document.createTextNode('interval #' + interval.toString() + ' - sayHello is ' + (isUndefined ? 'UNDEFINED' : 'DEFINED'));
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.body.appendChild(node);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.8/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to poll you cannot do much better than that. The proper reactive way would be `myObject` emitting an event when the method is ready and you subscribing to it.